# How can I create a sum of every n numbers?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with this column:

```
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
```

And I want to sum it every n numbers (Say 4). Intended output:

```
4
8
12
```

How can I do this? I know how to do rollsum, but wanted to know if there is any function to do this?

Comment: Your example is confusing.  It may look like you want `sum` per each unique values.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think that way. I just put those numbers for the sake of convenience of adding. :)

Comment: All of the examples in the other question are for _vectors_; since yours is already in a `data.frame` (i.e. the declaration overhead there is out of the way), you might be better off with a `data.table` solution: `setDT(df)[,sum(v),by=.(rep(seq_len(nrow(df)%/%n),each=n))]`

Answer (score 1):

```
X <- data.frame(value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3))
X$group = rep(1:(nrow(X)/4), each=4)

tapply(X$value, X$group, FUN = sum)
```

The hardest part here is assigning the groups.  See `?rep` for details there.